# How to clean install ubuntu 16.04 on my previously partitioned hard drive where Windows was installed before?

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, format

How can I install Ubuntu freshly on my laptop? The partition where my windows was installed previously, is completely empty right now i like to install Ubuntu there. What should I do to install it there so that it boots up from the hard drive not from any live DVD or USB. Right now I'm using live Ubuntu without installing off of my DVD. Please help to with the procedure to install it to my hard drive partition.